# Filling Color Gradient between points

Tags: python, gradient, pixel

I have a bunch of (x,y) type points. Corresponding to these points there is an associated value (within a specific range). These values can be used to put color to them (using some color map).
If we now use these (x,y) and color we can have a pixelated image (with a color pixel at each x,y). Is there an easy way to fill the pixels between so that I get a sensible gradient of colors.

TLDR: How to fill pixels within a boundary when you know values at nearby pixels?

The thing which makes it difficult for me is I have much more pixels to fill than the number of already colored pixels.

Also can I control the gradient type (linear, quadratic etc.)

Comment: Something like import numpy as np import matplotlib.pyplot as plt x = np.random.rand(100) y = np.random.rand(100) t = np.arange(100) plt.scatter(x, y, c=t) plt.show()

Comment: Obviously for me x,y as well as t is not random. I want to fill a color gradient between the points